# Create sub folders in the controller without Areas

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, directory-structure

I am developing a MVC 3 Web app and I want to create something like this:

```
/Controller
      /Blog
         BogController.cs
         ViewsController.cs
         ArticlesController.cs
      /Customers
         SalesController.cs
         ProductsController.cs          
      HomeController.cs
/Views
     /Blog
        Index.aspx
        Summary.aspx
        /Views
           Index.aspx
           Admin.aspx
           Show.aspx
       /Articles
          Show.aspx
          Admin.aspx
    /Customers
       /Sales
          Index.aspx
          Totals.aspx
       /Products
          Index.aspx
          Promotions.aspx
     /Home
       Index.aspx
```

[Create sub folders in the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748960/asp-net-mvc-create-sub-folders-in-the-controller)

But in the solution that they answer to this guy was for MVC 2 and in MVC 3 the property MapAreas doesn't exits (or at least it doesn't appear to me)

So what i can do to build an structure like /Admin/Users/EditUser?id=2 for example?

If i need to create a route rule, can you write me an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routing rules are definitely the way to go.  To make a structure like you mentioned, write the route rule like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "user_routing",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}?id={id}",
    new { }
);
```

Then create a controller named UsersController, and an action with id as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult EditUser(string id) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was reading about how to do it in this way and finally i found the way:  routes.MapRoute(
                 "AdminUsers",
                 "Admin/Users/{action}/{id}",
                 new { controller = "AdminUsers", action = "Index" ,id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );

Comment: The problem is this will match `Admin/[AnyController]/` and `/Users` without `Admin/` if you still have the default route. I'm additionally seeing `@Html.ActionLink` generating all links under the `Admin/` route.

Answer (score 10):

Consider using [MVC3 Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). You can create an Admin area for that.

Comment: Thanks, but this way create a lot of staff, finnly I will opt to do creating routes.

Comment: I originally used areas when they were first available, but found they were more trouble than they were worth. Principally, defining the area in each action link, many third-party bits and pieces not being compatible, etc. My two cents.

Comment: Not to mention it makes a mess of your project's file structure