# Where to put user specific stuff - url structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In all my project I have UserController which is used to display every users profile, and has only one action, something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string username)
```

But I am not sure where would I put stuff specific to **Current user**,example:

```
QuestionsController
AnswersController
```

**Option 1**

Should I add an action under each controller like this:

```
public ActionResult My()
```

which would look like:

```
/questions/my 
/answers/my
```

**Option 2**

I add controller `MyController` and actions Questions and Answers then I get something like:

```
/my/questions
/my/answers
```

**Option 3**

I add those actions to my user controller, so I get something like:

```
/user/questions/1/exampleuser/
/user/answers/1/exampleuser/
```

Which would be easiest to maintain and feel most natural for users?

Comment: @Anon Which part of question don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of urls

Option 2 feels natural, since it is account-specific information that you are fetching. Option 3 is decent, but clumsy. And definitely not Option 1.

I understand your concerns around having a single controller in Option 2. Infact you can still have a QuestionController and AnswerController, and use routing rules ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905343/create-sub-folders-in-the-controller-without-areas)) to retain the nice urls that option 2 gives.

Comment: That is my dilemma too :) Advantage of option one would be IMO ease to maintain since you wolud have to add only one additional action per controller, in option 2 and 3 you would have lot of actions,depending on things users can add and view.

Comment: One more advantage of Option 1 would be DRY views since you could reuse Index view for example. 2 would be pain to localize if I ever want to go down that road